# Status of perl scripts run from bash scripts

Tags: linux, perl, bash, shell

As far as I know we can use `$?` to get the result of a command we executed and it will return a non-zero result on error and a 0 result on success provided that the programmer kept the convention.
But what about when we run perl scripts?
I am new in perl but I think that perl scripts return `1` if they are part of a module otherwise they don't return anything.
So how can I know what happened to a perl script I run?

Answer (score 7):

Perl scripts behave the same when run from the shell.
Having `test.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
exit(0); # or just exit
```

running:

```
./test.pl && echo "OK" || echo $?
OK
```

Having

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
exit(123);
```

running:

```
./test.pl && echo "OK" || echo $?
123
```

Having

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
die;
```

running:

```
./test.pl && echo "OK" || echo $?
Died at ./test.pl line 2.
255
```

So:

- Exiting from perl script with 0 (or nothing) will be `true` in shell.
- Exiting from perl script with a (byte) value other than 0 will be `false` in shell and `$?` will give you the exit value.
- Exiting from perl script with `die` will be `false` in shell and `$?` will be 255 (in my case - I checked it).

Comment: It's worth noting that terminating a Perl program with `die` results in the error code `-1`. No explicit `exit` is needed.

Comment: For clarity, *a value other than 0* still must fit in a byte. (And just in case it's still not clear, `die();` in perl will result in an exit status of 255.)

Comment: You both are right. I'll add this to the answer. Thanks - However, bash (in my case) gave me 255 instead of -1.

Comment: `./test.pl && echo "OK" || echo $?` the `echo $?` is `>0` on failure but why is `OK` printed on success?

Comment: Because of `&&` - `and` binds stronger than `or`. Read it as "(test.pl and (on success) echo "OK") or (otherwise) echo the error.

So: it test.pl succeeds, result will be true for the shell, so it continues to evaluate the term `test.pl && echo "OK"`, echoing the string. `echo` also returns a true value, so `test.pl && echo` is also true. Now there's no need for shell to continue to evaluate the `or` part introduced with `||` since the final result is already given: it will be true (regardless of the return value of what might come afterwards). So `echo "$?" is not executed anymore.

Comment: I believe the shell's exit status uses an unsigned char, so -1 == 255